# Can I POST in Ajax but still using ASP.Net MVC5 Model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-ajax

Hi I have a problem and was hoping you could help.

My page uses MVC5 Model for my custom object, but I have a timer in Jquery and after completion of the Timer I want to redirect the page to another page but it needs to pass my Model.

The code I want to execute looks like this in a submit form format

```
        using (Html.BeginForm("SkipQuestion", "Test"))
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.QuestionModel.Question)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.StudentAnswer.QuestionId) 

            <button type="submit" style="border: 0; background: transparent">
                <img src="../../assets/arrow_right.png" width="50" alt="submit" />
            </button>
        }
```

I have  2 HiddenFor that is connected to my HTML.Model

Now I have this function for my timer that if it is completed it will call my POST which is SkipQuestion in Test Controller.

```
   timerComplete = function () {
                 $.ajax({
                     url: '@Url.Action("SkipQuestion","Test")',
                     type: 'POST', 
                     success: function (data) { 
                     },
                     error: function () {
                         alert("error");
                     }
                 });
```

My problem now is that I don't know how I can call my the Model + the hiddenfor

Comment: Whats the signature of `SkipQuestion`?

Comment: signature? sorry I dont know what is that

Edit* If signature you mean the function overload and arguments:
public async Task<ActionResult> SkipQuestion(QuestionAndAnswer qNa) 
This is the complete argument

Comment: What parameters does it have e.g. `public ActionResult SkipQuestion(int ID)`? In other words, what to you want to pass to the method

Comment: public async Task<ActionResult> SkipQuestion(QuestionAndAnswer qNa)

Comment: If you need to post the whole model, try adding `data: $('form').serialize(), dataType: "json",` to the ajax function (although I suspect you don't really need to pass the whole model)

Comment: if I serialize it doesn't that mean my Post Function will be expecting a serialize string?

Comment: No it should bind to your model (there are a few gotchas). But do you really need to post back the whole model. The name of you method suggests you probably only need the ID of the question (since its being skipped) so you could just use `data: { ID: @Model.QuestionID }` (or whatever the property name is) and change the signature to `public ActionResult SkipQuestion(int ID)`

Comment: I intentionally remove that but the Model has 10 more arguments that are needed to be pass

Comment: Then use `data: $('form').serialize()` as I indicated previously. It will post back all the values of your form controls and will be bound to your model

Comment: Can your timer call the click event on the button to submit the form (the hidden fields will be passed then) instead of doing an ajax call? you can create an Ajax.BeginForm if you want to use Ajax.

Comment: Oh is that possible? I never thought of that